# NUMA placement failed, performance might be affected

Tags: ubuntu, xen, numa

I'm running SuperMicro 6048R-E1CR36H Storageserver on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.03 LTS and Xen

Kernel:  4.4.0-97-generic
Xen: xen-hypervisor-4.6-amd64:amd64/xenial-security 4.6.5-0ubuntu1.2

Problem: when I run xl create or xl restore, I get this error message:

```
libxl: notice: libxl_numa.c:499:libxl__get_numa_candidate: NUMA placement failed, performance might be affected
```

On other xen-systems I haven't noticed the same message, how would I be able to fix this error?

Here is the xl info. I'm running 24 cores on 2x Xeon E5-2620 v3 chips.
https://ark.intel.com/products/83352/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-v3-15M-Cache-2_40-GHz

```
host                   : myserver
release                : 4.4.0-97-generic
version                : #120-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 19 17:28:18 UTC 2017
machine                : x86_64
nr_cpus                : 24
max_cpu_id             : 23
nr_nodes               : 2
cores_per_socket       : 6
threads_per_core       : 2
cpu_mhz                : 2400
hw_caps                : bfebfbff:2c100800:00000000:00007f00:77fefbff:00000000:00000021:000037ab
virt_caps              : hvm hvm_directio
total_memory           : 130967
free_memory            : 5
sharing_freed_memory   : 0
sharing_used_memory    : 0
outstanding_claims     : 0
free_cpus              : 0
xen_major              : 4
xen_minor              : 6
xen_extra              : .5
xen_version            : 4.6.5
xen_caps               : xen-3.0-x86_64 xen-3.0-x86_32p hvm-3.0-x86_32 hvm-3.0-x86_32p hvm-3.0-x86_64 
xen_scheduler          : credit
xen_pagesize           : 4096
platform_params        : virt_start=0xffff800000000000
xen_changeset          : 
xen_commandline        : placeholder
cc_compiler            : gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
cc_compile_by          : stefan.bader
cc_compile_domain      : canonical.com
cc_compile_date        : Fri Oct 13 15:42:52 UTC 2017
xend_config_format     : 4
```

Comment: Without more information really it's impossible to say. The required information is how many CPUs of what type do you have? What  does 'xl info' report about the CPU?

Comment: I edited the question to show xl info.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this message on Debian when I forgot to limit Dom0 memory.
For GRUB2 add or edit the following line in the /etc/default/grub file:
GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN_DEFAULT="dom0_mem=512M,max:512M"

More about this: https://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/Xen_Project_Best_Practices

Answer (score 0):

From `xl info` output, it looks like you have very little available free memory. You're almost certainly trying to launch a VM with more memory that what's available, that could be the reason for this message (I suppose that some VMs are already running on this host).

I suppose that `grep vmx /proc/cpuinfo` returns something, too?

Comment: grep vmx /proc/cpuinfo return empty so I'll check my BIOS settings. There is 128GB of total memory on the system. The command `free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
    Mem:         110146       41342       61781         499        7022       
    62287
    Swap:          3904        3157         746`

Comment: @PHZ.fi-Pharazon so you have virtualization turned off. Probably not a good thing on a virtualization server :) Is your xf info output still the same 6 months later?